# LocationManger only gives me one update

Tags: android, service, android-service, locationmanager, locationlistener

**What I'm trying to do**

---

Hello Guys, I'm trying to create a service which post every hour a Locationupdate to my Server. The Code seems to work, when I start the Service, It automaticly posts the first locationupdate, afterwards nothing happens. But the strange thing is, sometimes it does sometimes not ...

**Question**

---

So what do I need to change in my code that my locationmanager puts every hour a locationupdate. If you have a great tutorial or some codesamples it would be great!

Comment: why not 60 * 60 * 1000 instead of 100?

Comment: oh i calculated this one false, it isn't a hour. But well also when I set the time to 6000 (6sec) it only gives me one locationupdate... :(

Comment: First You have to test like ....1.Stay on one point and reduce time Just 5 mnt and check its works then Change your geolocation and check what Happens .Then rise your time ,And After 1 hour you have to call LocationManager to get GeoLocation and Dont Put it in OnLocationChanged Because if you are in same location its cant sent....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your device turned of the CPU to save battery power and your service will not receive an update. Consider using an alarm for the updates, which just requests one location update (there is a method for in the location manager this since API 9) or use the WakeLock in your service (which is a waste of battery power if you need just one update every hour).

See here for more info on the alarm manager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Ditto to the previous answer, you shouldn't be using requestLocationUpdates for this.  You should be using an AlarmManager every hour, and then do a .requestSingleUpdate().

By the way, the time you give it is mostly bogus, the device just uses that as a hint, you can expect the frequency to be much higher than what you request.

And remember, it's extremely possible that an hour later, your app will have gotten killed off by android's process manager, so it will be dead anyway.  In any case, an AlarmManager would be the solution to this.